# How to find out when the keyboard opens the first time? iphone

Tags: iphone, keyboard

How to find out when the keyboard opens the first time in iOS? I want to know only the time when you click on a cell(that contains a UITextField) and the keyboard opens. After that I navigate through the UITextFields using a toolbar that contains the buttons previous and next.

Using the following code, calls keyboardWillShow when navigating through UITextFields, even though the keyboard seems to remain open after the first click on the UITextField. This method doesn't help me for my purpose.

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

 - (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Notification..It may help you

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                               object:nil];
```

And in that keyboardWillShow method remove observer like this.

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you Murali for your answer.:)

Comment: I tried to explain my question better, because the first time is was a little vague.

Comment: Just remove that Observer in keyboardWillShow method..So keyboardWillShow will not call again.

Comment: I succeeded. Thank you a lot!:)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `-viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

Then the method `keyboardWillShow:` would look like this:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
  if (firstOpen) {
    //do your stuff
    firstOpen = NO;
  } else {
    //do smth else
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer I was searching for.:) But I have to wait 5 minutes to accept it.

Comment: Calling this function after first time is no need....So we can remove observer...

Comment: @Novarg I edited the question, I didn't explain well enough at the beginning.